# Update bound JLabel text in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea, jlabel

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA's form editor and bound a JLabel to my mouse_input class.  My goal is to get the mouse's x and y coordinates on the form and print them to a label.   Everything is going swell and my code generally works, I can set the JLabel text to x and y's values, but only once when the form loads.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to update the values regularly after the form load.  I'm new to Java and IntelliJ so I very well may be missing something simple.  Here's my code.

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import static javax.swing.JFrame.*;

public class mouse_input {
    private JPanel mouse_pad;
    private JLabel label;

    private static int x;
    private static int y;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                displayJframe();
            }
        });

    }
    static void displayJframe(){
        // Create blank content frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mouse Input");
        frame.setContentPane(new mouse_input().mouse_pad);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.validate();

        // Add mouse motion listener
        frame.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                // It doesn't like me deleting this
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                x = e.getX();
                y = e.getY();
                frame.revalidate();
            }
        });

        // Set cursor type
        frame.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));

        // Display frame
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createUIComponents() {
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setText("X" + x + "Y" + y);
    }
}
```

Now I've done some research and poked about and seen that I might be able to create a JLabel from scratch, but I really wanted to try and see if I could use IntelliJ's gui editor exclusively, and I've not seen anything of this nature around.  Again though, I may just be a giant idiot.  I'd appreciate any feedback.

Comment: do `label.setText("X" + x + "Y" + y);` in `mouseMoved`

Comment: @ScaryWombat that was definitely my first move, but alas `Non-static field, 'label' cannot be referenced from a static context.`  Which does stand to reason.  The bound label's non static properties are definitely what has made this as hard as it is.

Comment: `static void displayJframe` make non-static, instantiate a `mouse_input` - also is `createUIComponents` being called?

Comment: Ok, so changing `static void displayJframe` to `public void display Jframe` allows me to do alot that I couldn't before like move `label.setText("X" + x + "Y" + y);` into `mouseMoved` and call `createUIComponents` (it was not called before, I couldn't call it from anywhere).  But now main doesn't like displayJframe so much and I'm left chasing static and non static fragments. As for `mouse_input`, like I said, I'm new to Java, would you mind telling me how to correctly instantiate `mouse_input?`.

Comment: @Abra I think I agree with your recommendation. ScaryWombat's code below looks like it definitely works but it fails to satisfy one of my main goals with this small project and that's to use the editor exclusively. But oh well, I guess there's time to learn after I've gotten a firm grasp on more basics.  Thank you for your advice.

Comment: I have fixed your code but I'm off to work now and I don't want to just post the code without explanation. I will post an answer after I finish work today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I ran the code you posted, I got a `NullPointerException`. Here is part of the stack trace. (Note that my environment is JDK 13.0.1 on [64 bit] Windows 10.)

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: contentPane cannot be set to null.
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JRootPane.setContentPane(JRootPane.java:598)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.setContentPane(JFrame.java:679)
    at generalp/guitests.mouse_input.displayJframe(mouse_input.java:27)
```

This line of the code you posted caused the error.

```java
frame.setContentPane(new mouse_input().mouse_pad);
```

That's because `mouse_pad` is never initialized.
This is easily fixed.

```java
private JPanel mouse_pad = new JPanel();
```

When I run the changed code, the following window is displayed.

[image: mousinp0]

This is because a `JPanel`, like all *Swing* containers, has no defined size because it takes on the size of its contained [GUI] components. In fact, method `pack()` resizes the `JFrame` to be big enough to hold all the contained components and the only contained component is a zero sized `JPanel`. So for the code you posted, in order to have a decent sized window, we need to explicitly set a size. So instead of `pack()` we need (for example)

```java
frame.setSize(400, 300);
```

Now when I run the updated code, I get

[image: mousinp1.png]

Where is the `label`? According to the code you posted, it is never added to the `frame`. You want to add two components to the `frame`, namely `mouse_pad` and `label`. If you set `mouse_pad` as the "content pane", then you have nowhere and no way to add the `label`. This is where *layout manager* becomes relevant. Unfortunately, if you are new to *Swing* and you rely on the GUI builder, it is not obvious how to utilize the *layout manager* to organize all the components you wish to display. Learning the basics, in my opinion, is important. The GUI builder is for programmers who know *Swing* well and know how to utilize the builder to save them time and effort. It is not a tool for learning *Swing* or for shortening the learning curve. So as someone who learned the basics, I know that the default layout manager for the content pane is `BorderLayout`, so in the code you posted I now replace the call to method `setContentPane()` with the following.

```java
frame.add(mouse_pad, BorderLayout.CENTER);
createUIComponents(); // in order to initialize member 'label'
frame.add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

Finally, you need to add a `MouseMotionListener` to a component that receives mouse motion events. This is not `JFrame` but `JPanel`, i.e. `mouse_pad` in this case. Also, a GUI builder may not let you know about class `MouseMotionAdapter` which implements `MouseMotionListener` with empty methods, so if you write a class that extends `MouseMotionAdapter` you only need to implement the relevant methods and not all the methods, which explains what you noted in the following comment in the code you posted.

> `// It doesn't like me deleting this`

Here is the fixed code. It's not the best implementation but it answers your question which basically was:

> *My code doesn't work. How should I change it in order to make it work?*

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MouseInput {
    private JPanel mouse_pad = new JPanel();
    private JLabel label;

    private static int x;
    private static int y;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MouseInput instance = new MouseInput();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                instance.createUIComponents();
                instance.displayJframe();
            }
        });

    }
    public void displayJframe(){
        // Create blank content frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mouse Input");
        frame.add(mouse_pad, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // Add mouse motion listener
        mouse_pad.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                x = e.getX();
                y = e.getY();
                label.setText("X = " + x + " , Y = " + y);
            }
        });

        // Set cursor type
        frame.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));

        // Display frame
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createUIComponents() {
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setText("X = " + x + " , Y = " + y);
    }
}
```

For learning *Swing*, I recommend [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)
But if you are just starting with GUI programming in Java, have you considered *JavaFX* which is intended to be a more modern replacement for *Swing*.

Comment: Thanks for this extremely detailed response.  I implemented your suggested changes and it works.  It seems that I was somehow confusing JFrame and JPanel and didn't really understand their differences.  @ScaryWombat's code doesn't make the same important distinctions between the two that you do, which is why I marked yours as the accepted answer.  Creating an instance of the main class was another step I had no idea I should implement.   Thank you again and I'll be sure to take your advice on using the editor and checkout JavaFX.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a fresh application

```
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Make sure we have nice window decorations.
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Add the ubiquitous "Hello World" label.
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World");
    frame.getContentPane().add(label);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

 // Add mouse motion listener
    frame.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            // It doesn't like me deleting this
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            int x = e.getX();
            int y = e.getY();
            label.setText("X" + x + "Y" + y);
            frame.revalidate();
        }
    });

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
```

**credit to**
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/swing/java-swing-application-example/